# C-Lomuto Quicksort Exe does not work

Tags: c, error-handling, quicksort

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ARRAY_SIZE 10

void lomuto (int A[], int l, int r, int smallerAtLeft)
{
    if (smallerAtLeft == 1) //move elements smaller than pivot to the left and the greater ones to the right
    {
        int tmp, tmp2,pivot,i,j;
        pivot = A[r];
        i = l-1;
        for (j =0; j<r-1; j++)
        {
            if (A[j] <= pivot)
            {
                i++;
                tmp = A[i];
                A[i] = A[j]; 
                A[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
        tmp2 = A[i+1];
        A[i+1] = A[r];
        A[r] = tmp2;
     }

     if (smallerAtLeft == 0) //move elements smaller than pivot to the right and the greater ones to the left
     {
        int tmp3, tmp4,pivot,i,j;
        pivot = A[r];
        i = l-1;
        for (j=0; j<r-1; j++)
        {
            if (A[j]>= pivot)
            {
                i++;
                tmp3 = A[i];
                A[i] = A[j]; 
                A[j] = tmp3;
            }       
        }
        tmp4 = A[i+1];
        A[i+1] = A[r];
        A[r] = tmp4;
    }

}
void quicksort (int A[], int l, int r, int ascending)
{
    lomuto (A,l,r,ascending);   
}

int main()
{
    int testarray;
    int testArray[ARRAY_SIZE] = {4, 2, 5, 3, 6, 7, 8, 1, 0};
    quicksort (testarray,0,8,1);
    return testarray;
}
```

Good evening. 
Usually I search almost every forum and deepest threads for dubiety in my codes. 
But this time I did not found an answer that could help me. I would be so thankful if anyone could tell my why the code-exe stops working but during compiling there is no error showing onscreen. 
We have to implement the quicksort algorithm with the lomuto-partitioning. If the variable "smallerAtLeft" ist equal to 1, the array should be ordered by an increasing property and if its equal to 0 decreasingly.

Furthermore we have to implement to void functions like you see in the code. The "lomuto-fct" and the "quicksort-fct" that contains the lomuto one.

Maybe this Reverse-Lomuto-Thread will help some other people too in the future..

Comment: You have 2 vars spelled differently. You are passing the wrong 1. This should give a compiler error.

Comment: And what problems do you have with the code you show? What is the question you want to ask? Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @JohnnyMopp what variables do you mean? i and j?

Comment: In `main` you have `testarray` and `testArray`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "Process exited after 2.781 seconds with return value 3221225477" is the console output after trying to compile the code and getting an "task4.exe does not work anymore"-error. Due to the fact that im new into programming (for two weeks now) and this SPECIAL kind of problem regarding the Lomuto-reversed one has never been asked before, I wanted to ask whether some experienced programmers could help me achieving the code to run...

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thank you! Now it works without errors. But it does not return anything.. even though I have the return line rin the main() fction... 
I'm in despair, the whole assignment builds on this code (runtime analysis, recursive one,....)

Comment: In the call to `quicksort (testarray,0,8,1);` you are sending the *uninitialised* variable `int testarray` instead of the the array `int testArray[]`. Please enable compiler warnings. Likewise `return testarray;` is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: When you return a value from `main`, it's usually just used by the OS. My guess is that your teacher wants you to print the sorted array to stdout before exiting the program.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you understand what the return value from `main` is and what it's used for. It is usually an indicator of success and failure, with the typical values `0` for success and a small positive value for failure. There are even macros defined for this purpose in the `<stdlib.h>` header file: [`EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/EXIT_status).

If you want to see the sorted array you need to *print* it:

```
printf("Sorted array = {");
for (unsigned i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i)
{
    printf(" %d", testArray[i]);
}
printf(" }\n");
```

That of course requires you to pass the actual array to your sorting function.

Comment: Thank you sir, I really appreciate your help!.. and I'm sorry for my bad knowledge in C..